# Handling authentication of microservice at Gateway service in Spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, jwt, microservices, spring-cloud-gateway

I am learning authentication at gateway service in a microservices architecture. What i understood is

1. When the client makes a request, it needs to have a valid access token
2. The authentication of the requests is happening at the gateway level, the authorization at the microservice application level
3. Request is processed if authentication is success (Jwt token is valid)

My Questions are :

1. Is it really needed to have authentication at gateway service as well as individual microservice ? Because its redundant to have the same logic at both places (JWT Validation)
2. If not (only at gateway service), how can the individual microservice can be protected if the call is not via gateway ?

Comment: are the individual microservices accessible withouth passing through the gateway?

Comment: Even with gateway, microservice APIs are not accessible since i have enabled the spring security in microservice. I have to either disable security or perform jwt validation in microservice again. I dont want this as authentication is already done at gateway

Comment: ok, but how it SHOULD be in the end? only via gateway or also directly?

Comment: I want authentication only via gateway and directly they should be restricted
Or
If call is coming via gateway, token validation should not happen again

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the Microservices are accessed only via the gateway, the authentication can be delegated to the Gateway that then send the informations relative to the caller to the recipient microservice(via an header for instance).

It is important to restrict the access to the microservices to the Gateway only.

This can be done at network level if there is a firewall or a router in between or via code configuring the microservice with soething like this:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {

@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.authorizeRequests()
      .antMatchers("/login").permitAll()
      .antMatchers("/foos/**").hasIpAddress("11.11.11.11")
      .anyRequest().authenticated()
      .and()
      .formLogin().permitAll()
      .and()
      .csrf().disable();
}

// ...

}
```

This is the whitelisting part. Then you need to verify how to pass the information of the logged in user to the microservices from the Gateway. If you need more infow about the white listing check this article: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-whitelist-ip-range